# RMI lookup works but method invocation not

Tags: java, rmi

### UPDATE:

The problem is, that i'm using a kind of 2-way connection.

On client side, this works:

```
String a = this.lobby.getMsg();
```

and this not:

```
this.lobby.login((Player)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(player, 0));
```

and ideas?

---

---

I'm working on a java application which uses RMI for network communication.

On one computer everythings works good, but if i try to run it via the internet i ran into problems.

It seems, that the client is able to retreive the registry from the server and to lookup the lobby-object.
But if the client tries to call the login method of the lobby object via rmi, it takes very long time and i receive the following exception:

Strange thing is, that there is the wrong ip(the client ip) mentioned in this exception.
And if I run a client on the same machine as the server, it works perfectly.

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <client ip(should be server ip?)>; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Die Wartezeit für die Verbindung ist abgelaufen (=time out)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:160)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at $Proxy0.einloggen(Unknown Source)
    at Client.login(Client.java:64)
```

---

**Here is the relevant code:**

My server class:

```
    public static final int RMI_PORT = 55555;
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "xyz.com";

    /**
     * Startet Spielserver
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Server starten..");

        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", SERVER_IP);
        try {
            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
                System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            }

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(SERVER_IP, RMI_PORT);

            Lobby lobby = new LobbyImpl();
            UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(lobby, 0);
            registry.bind("Lobby", lobby);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client class:

```
public Client() {
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("xyz.com", Server.RMI_PORT);
            lobby = (Lobby) registry.lookup("Lobby");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.gui = new GUI(this);
    }

    public void login(String name) throws RemoteException {
        Player player = new Player(name);
        this.lobby.login((Player)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(player, 0));  
    }
```

Client startscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname $0)
java -classpath $SCRIPTDIR/bin Client
```

Server startscript:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname $0)

cd ${SCRIPTDIR}/bin
rmiregistry 55555 &
cd - 
java -classpath $SCRIPTDIR/bin -Djava.security.policy=$SCRIPTDIR/src/server.policy -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:$SCRIPTDIR/bin/ Server
killall rmiregistry
```

and last but not least my first (test) policy file:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

what could be the problem?

regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So i have not to catch the second exception. 

But concerning my problem it doesn't change something

Comment: As his lookup worked, obviously the bind worked as well. Not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at item A.1 of the RMI FAQ on the RMI home page. The problem here is that the wrong IP address is being embedded into the remote stub. So the lookup works, because you are specifying the target IP address yourself in the client, but when you execute the remote method you are relying on the IP address in the stub, which is wrong. The solution is either to correct your /etc/hosts file or to set the system property java.rmi.server.hostname at the server JVM.

Comment: but I'm doing this already with `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", SERVER_IP);` in the Server class
or?

Comment: @CaptnLenz In the server JVM, yes. So if you're doing that, either the IP address is wrong, or unreachable, or you're doing it too late, after the remote object has been already exported. As you're getting a connect timeout rather than a refusal I would say the IP address or the network topology is wrong. Can you *really* ping that IP address from the client?

Comment: it seems, that my problem has gone into another direction. Please see my update to the question.

Comment: @CaptnLenz Either the server IP displayed is as expected or it isn't. If it is, and you are getting connection timeouts, that IP address isn't reachable from the client, and you cannot possibly be able to telnet to that IP:port from that client. If it isn't as exoected, you aren't setting it correctly inJava.rmi.server.hostname.

Comment: my client is able to ping (and telnet) to the server, but the server is not able to ping to the client. So the problem is likely, that the server cannot call methods on the client(here on the exported player object) and this throws the exception

Comment: @CaptnLenz So in that case you need to organize the client to have a publicly usable IP address, and maybe to set java.rmi.server.hostname appropriately at the client JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: <wrong ip of the server>;
```

I would check you can ping that server and telnet to the service point.

Comment: i can ping to both, the wrong ip (really don't know where it comes) and the correct one (which i have specified in my sourcecode)

What do you mean with ` telnet to the service point.` ?

Comment: Use `telnet {hostname} {port}` or similar to see the service is listening (and you can connect to it)

Comment: okay, i can telnet to my rmi server on the correct ip. But the ip address mentioned in the exception doesn't work. So it seems the network level is okay and the problem is in my programm?

Comment: It appears the server is registering an incorrect IP address for itself.

Comment: ok an update. the wrong ip is the ip of the client! (Don't ask me, why  i didn't noticed this until now)

Comment: If he got that exception it is already *certain* that (a) he can ping that host and (b) he cannot telnet to the port. That's all implied by the exception.