# Java RMI - Lookup Success , but method call fails - Onpremise Vs AWS

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, rmi

I have a java code which makes connection to a Java RMI server - lookup followed by method invocation. 
Both machine are under the same firewall in onpremise and works as expected.
When my client/java moved to AWS, the RMI server is still running in on-premise.. But here in this case, it fails with below error..

```
Lookup success, method call failed.. 

Lookup for Remote Object Successful.

ErrorMessage:startupFunction : RemoteException Caught.. Connection refused to host: XXXXX ; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
```

PS : I see similiar issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224934/rmi-lookup-works-but-method-invocation-not), but nothing seems to work in my case

Comment: Seems your firewall/machine port settings issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your remote object on a fixed port, and open that port in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding the port used by RMI Method.. We ran the request from on-premise and in the RMI host we ran netstat and captured the port list.. This way we could figure out the port and enabled in Security group in AWS.. thanks all for your help..

Comment: Eh? If you export the remote object on a fixed port, no discovery is necessary; and if you don't, no amount of discovery about what happened last time will help you with respect to what will happen next time.